# Retrieve the first item from a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm having trouble getting the first item from a list. The data is added to the list from a text file however, the system is returning `System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__25'1[System.String]` instead of the first item in the list.

The following is my implementation

```
string[] inputData = rawInputData.Split(',');
List<string> splitData = new List<string>(inputData.Length);
splitData.AddRange(inputData);
var numberOfCaves = splitData.Take(1);
Console.Write(numberOfCaves);
```

I am unsure as why this is happening and any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `FirstOrDefault`.

You can also save yourself a lot of footwork, as `Split` returns an array (`IEnumerable`) already. So you don't have to create a new list and add it

The problem is essentially, `Take` Returns an `IEnumerable` (a list for all intents and purposes, that hasn't been traversed yet), `Console.WriteLine` doesn't know how to convert it to a `string` implicitly so it writes its type name

```
var result = rawInputData.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();

if(result == null) // checks if there are no elements and results null
  Console.WriteLine("darn");
else    
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

[String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

[Enumerable.Take(IEnumerable, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence.
>
> - **Returns** `IEnumerable<TSource>` An IEnumerable that contains the specified number of elements from the start of the input sequence.

[Enumerable Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> - The methods in this class provide an implementation of the standard query operators for querying data sources that implement
>     IEnumerable. The standard query operators are general purpose
>     methods that follow the LINQ pattern and enable you to express
>     traversal, filter, and projection operations over data in any
>     .NET-based programming language.
> - The majority of the methods in this class are defined as extension methods that extend IEnumerable. This means they can be called like
>     an instance method on any object that implements IEnumerable.
> - Methods that are used in a query that returns a sequence of values do not consume the target data until the query object is enumerated.
>     This is known as deferred execution. Methods that are used in a query
>     that returns a singleton value execute and consume the target data
>     immediately.

**Update**

> As a side note, result can never be null here. – Antonín Lejsek

Which is indeed correct

`string.Split` Will return at least 1 element

Comment: As a side note, result can never be null here.

Answer (score 4):

Use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead. These [eagerly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation) get the first item. `Take` uses [deferred execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/), so what you are actually printing is the `ToString()` of the iterator, not the value of the first item.

The best clue when you experience these kind of issues with LINQ is that you should assume that anything returning `IEnumerable<T>` is deferred (not always true though) and that anything returning a single item is eager (e.g. `Max`, `First`, `Last`, `Single`, and so on).

Answer (score 4):

Aside of First or FirstOrDefault you can also directly access the array entries.

```
string[] inputData = rawInputData.Split(',');
string first = inputData[0];
string second = inputData[1];
...
```

But you have to make sure that the array index you access really exists. Otherwise you get an Exception for accessing non existent entry.